# How does Folders work in Visual Studio Code? I cant link Files from folders to my project

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory

Folders that I created:

[image: Folders that I created]

In the picture, you see my folders, because I want the code to be in nice groups, so I don't lose the overview.

Sadly, my problem now is: I can't add filepaths & link the files with each other.

Things i´ve tried:

```
background-image: url(flexbox-parent-image.jpg);
background-image: url(\images\flexbox-parent-image.jpg);
background-image: url(website\images\flexbox-parent-image.jpg);
```

And if i use the full path with C/Users it doesnt even work if im not using any folder.
Thanks in advance for the help!

I've googled and searched but i dont find any solution.

Comment: background-image: url(images\flexbox-parent-image.jpg);

Comment: The paths will be relative to where you created your "website" folder, in there you should have an "images" folder, just copy the images into that folder. then in VSCode you should see a refresh button, click that, and if the images have been found then they will appear in your folder/file list.

Comment: @user20716902 First of all thanks for your time. I just realized everything works with pathing whenever the HTML file is not inside a folder. I just ask myself why? 
It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: it's not yet clear what this has to do with VS Code. The interpretation of paths in CSS is determined by the web server when there is one. are you using a web server to serve your site? what web server are you using? If you're just using the file:// protocol in your browser, then you need to use relative paths.